# Plotting multiple data values inside function call

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I want to plot multiple subplots of scatter plots inside a function, after calling the `*args` parameter to unpack `(x,y)` input values. However, I keep getting a simple error:

> ValueError: s must be a scalar, or float array-like with the same size as x and y

I cannot seem to solve it even after changing the function into alternative orders of `args`. Here is my sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.pyplot import plt

x = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], 
              [0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.2, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.5, 0.8, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.2, 0.1, 0.5, 0.6],
              ['r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'r', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b', 'b']])


values = pd.DataFrame(x.T, columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

X = values[values['c'] == 'r'].iloc[ : , 0:2 ].values
Y = values[values['c'] == 'b'].iloc[ : , 0:2 ].values

def test(*args):
    figs, axs = plt.subplots( 1 , 2 , figsize = ( 8 , 8 ) )
    for xy , ax in zip( args , axs.flat ) :
        print(xy)
        ax.scatter(*xy)

test(X, Y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have achieved it with the follow, so perhaps there is a cleaner alternative?

```
def test(*args):
    figs, axs = plt.subplots( 1 , 2 , figsize = ( 8 , 8 ) )
    xy = np.array(args)
    for x_y , ax in zip( xy , axs.flat ) :
        (x, y) = np.hsplit(np.ndarray.flatten(x_y), 2)
        ax.scatter(x, y)

test(X, Y)

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

okay ... this is the solution to your problem ... this is probably as incomprehensible as your code.

```py
def t(*args):
    figs, axs = plt.subplots( 1 , 2 , figsize = ( 8 , 8 ) )
    for xy , ax in zip( zip(*args) , axs.flat ) :
        print(xy)
        ax.scatter(*xy)

t(X.transpose(), Y.transpose())
```

now let's convert this to python code...
you should know everything about the function just by looking at the function, so *args is useful for something "extra" than the intended behavior of the function.

1. separate X and Y from args, because they are used inside the function explicitly.
2. avoid zip unless the arguments are simple, while nesting generators is performant it's bad for code quality, in your case i'd go for enumerate instead since i am indexing into an array, which needs to be as descriptive as possible.
3. make your calls descriptive, `*xy` is not descriptive, what is this variable ? is it a tuple ? an ndarray ? what will unpacking it result in ? if you are passing X and Y in it then pass X and Y directly.

```py
def t(*args):
    X,Y = args
    figs, axs = plt.subplots(1, 2, figsize=(8, 8))
    for i, ax in enumerate(axs):
        print(X[:, i], Y[:, i])
        ax.scatter(X[:, i], Y[:, i])

t(X, Y)
```

Comment: The `zip` alternative was very helpful! Unfortunately, I cannot use your second method which was why I specifically mentioned to have an answer that uses `args`. In this case, `xy` denotes `(x, y)` because we're unpacking it. It is largely down to preference. However, I wanted to avoid all the `transposes` because this makes the actual dataset more complex to work with. For now, my answer seems to get the job done cleanly.

Comment: @Emil11 just make sure you delete the code after you are done using it, so none else has to read it ... unless you are intentionally obfuscating your code.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion however its used inside a class call and not directly used as a dynamic function. Therefore, the class this is embedded in won't be of use to others. It is really just supposed to be simple. On my end, I can understand it very easily. Down to preference largely I reckon.

Comment: @Emil11 i modified the second function to show how it may be done "cleanly" while maintaining `*args` and avoiding the 3 copies of data that you made, the reason i am just pointing out the code low quality is because you and everyone on your team will hate you later for it, it is not "Down to preference" as you may think, you will start accumulating hate from from anyone that uses your code.

Comment: Thank you for the opinion, I will not take it lightly. Therefore, I will consider your approach and implement cleaner interpretations.